# Laravel 8 whereHas and whereBetween has no effect

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Having this code:

```
$resultCards = Posts::with('subcategory')->whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use ($main_categories,$sub_categories)  {
                $q->whereIn('id', $sub_categories);
                $q->orWhereHas('category', function($query) use ($main_categories) {
                    $query->whereIn('id', $main_categories);
                });
            })
```

This works and fetches the relevant records correctly.

Now I want to filter the result like this:

```
$resultCards->whereBetween('price', [0,3500]);
$results = $resultCards->paginate(5);
```

This doesnt change the result. It does work if I remove one of the whereHas. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually overcomplicating things. This works:

```
$resultCards = Posts::with('subcategory')->whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use ($main_categories)  {                
                $q->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($main_categories) {
                    $query->whereIn('id', $main_categories);
                });
            });
```